# Public and Static Variables

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run a code to check if the user is logged in on a server. If the user is logged then the public variable loggedIn = true. This value should be preserved so the user could use my user defined function.

Pseudo code:

```
Public loggedIn as boolean

Sub check_if_is_logged()

  'Code to check if the user is logged
  'if logged then loggedIn = true

end sub

function user_defined()

  'check to see if it is logged
  if loggedIn = false then 
Exit Function

end function
```

But every time I run the code the values goes back to false and I can't use the function. Is there a way to declare a public and static variable at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

The function `user_defined` will always return `False` regardless of whether the variable `loggedIn` is `True` or `False`, unless the function declares a return value.  So, this will give the *appearance* that the `loggedIn` public variable is not persisting as desired/expected.  I suspect if you debug your code and step through it, you will observe that to be the case: `loggedIn` correctly is `True`, but the `user_defined` function is not returning the value correctly.

This apparently works for me

```
Public loggedIn As Boolean

Sub check_if_is_logged()

    loggedIn = True

End Sub

Function user_defined()
    Dim ret As Boolean

    If loggedIn Then ret = True

    user_defined = ret
End Function
```

In the `loggedIn` procedure I simply assume the user is logged in (of course you would have logic that determines whether True or False).

Then, if I query the `user_defined` function, by doing `?user_defined` in the immediate window, the result is `True`.

The value of `loggedIn` does **not** revert back to `False`.

If you observe something different, then check your logic which could be mistaken, or perhaps you are doing something to `End` runtime which would clear out the public variables.

**NOTE:** This will not persist through an `End` statement (although it should persist through `End Sub`, `End Function`, `End Type`, `End Enum`, etc.).  This will also not persist beyond closing the workbook/etc.  You would need to save the value to a `Name` in the workbook, or to the `CustomDocumentProperties` collection.

Comment: I think the key is that the OP is never assigning a return value to `user_function` before the function exits. In that case, it will always return what ever it was defaulted to, which seems to be `0`, or `False`

Comment: @FreeMan right! the function `user_defined` would return `False` regardless of whether the variable `loggedIn` is `True` or `False`, unless the function declares a return value.  Good catch.  So, this could give the *appearance* that the `loggedIn` public variable is not persisting as desired/expected.